# Logstash Kafka output plugin

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash

I am looking to use the Logstash Kafka output plugin to post events to a Kafka topic.

While logstash is pushing logs what happens if Kafka server goes down suddenly for some reason? By the time we bring back Kafka, do we loose data/events? If not, how does logstash handle this?

Please clarify

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you can read Ruby, you can see [in the source code](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-kafka/blob/master/lib/logstash/outputs/kafka.rb), there are various conditions where it will attempt to retry in the event of exceptions, but after which, it'll drop records.

Answer (score 0):

I should have read the documentation a bit more thoroughly. The documentation of the [retries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-kafka.html#plugins-outputs-kafka-retries) option 3 explains the behavior and suggested configurations clearly.